# MySql order by with union duplicate results

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, union

Here is my query

```
(SELECT *, 1 as ob FROM `jokes` WHERE `flags` < 5 AND (`title` LIKE "%only three doors%" OR `joke` LIKE "%only three doors%") )
UNION
(SELECT *, 2 as ob FROM `jokes` WHERE `flags` < 5 AND (`title` LIKE "%only%" OR `joke` LIKE "%only%") )
UNION
(SELECT *, 3 as ob FROM `jokes` WHERE `flags` < 5 AND (`title` LIKE "%three%" OR `joke` LIKE "%three%") )
UNION
(SELECT *, 4 as ob FROM `jokes` WHERE `flags` < 5 AND (`title` LIKE "%doors%" OR `joke` LIKE "%doors%"))
 ORDER BY `ob` ASC, `ups` DESC,`downs` ASC LIMIT 0, 30
```

Now my problem with this is I am getting duplicate results. Is there a way to modify this so I don't get duplicates.

The order of the selects are more important than the ups or downs.

I'd also like to note that the number of select statements changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT jokes.*
     , CASE WHEN title LIKE '%only three doors%' 
              OR joke LIKE '%only three doors%'
              THEN 1 
            WHEN title LIKE '%only%' 
              OR joke LIKE '%only%'
              THEN 2
            WHEN title LIKE '%three%' 
              OR joke LIKE '%three%'
              THEN 3
            ELSE 4
       END as ob 
FROM jokes 
WHERE flags < 5 
  AND ( title LIKE '%only%' 
     OR joke LIKE '%only%'
     OR title LIKE '%three%' 
     OR joke LIKE '%three%'
     OR title LIKE '%doors%' 
     OR joke LIKE '%doors%'
      )
ORDER BY ob ASC
       , ups DESC
       , downs ASC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: Looks alright until the part after the flag condition. Is that even necessary?

Comment: Also, if it doesn't satisfy any of those conditions in the case, I don't want it. So having the else 4 statement will just grab the rest of the rows won't it, and add them to the end? Can i just take that line out?

Comment: The `ELSE 4` is for the case when `title LIKE '%doors%' or joke LIKE '%doors%'`

Comment: The part in the `WHERE`, after the `flags < 5` is needed, yes.

Comment: Seems to work great. Changed the `ELSE 4` to another `WHEN` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously going to get duplicate results, because you're adding in the literal number value after the `SELECT *`.

That's going to make each row distinct, so the `UNION` won't be able to remove otherwise duplicate rows.

Comment: I know all this. I'm asking if anyone knows a way to make this work without duplicates.